# Why does Excel SUMIF function return #ERROR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Learning SUMIF right now on excel. Why does this line work in a cell:

```
 =SUMIF(A:A,"<1/3/2020" ,F2:F102)
```

But this one gives me "#ERROR!" where cell O2 is the date 1/3/2020

```
 =SUMIF(A:A, <O2 ,F2:F102)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<O2` to `"<" & O2`

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "<" & O2 ,F2:F102)
```